# ArrayList items unreachable after sending through the interface

Tags: java, android, interface, android-fragments

The problem is I can't retrieve a `Integer` values from the`ArrayList<Integer>` which was sent from `TimePickerFragment` through the interface to the FragmentActivity. When I try to get saved values (see FragmentActivity below) I'm getting  "incompatible types. Required: java.lang.Integer, Found: java.lang.Object".

TimePickerFragment:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

Listener mListener;

// declaration of the interface
public interface Listener {
    public void onUserTimeChoice(ArrayList dataSet);
}


// registration of the listener
public void registerListener(Listener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    ArrayList<Integer> mAList = new ArrayList();

    mAList.add(hourOfDay);
    mAList.add(minute);
    mListener.onUserTimeChoice(mAList);
}
}
```

FragmentActivity (an extract):

```
@Override
public void onUserTimeChoice(ArrayList dataSet) {

    Integer hour = dataSet.get(0);   //  <--- incompatible types
    Integer minute = dataSet.get(1); // <--- incompatible types

}
```

Comment: Did you tried to change the interface method to public void onUserTimeChoice(ArrayList<Integer> dataSet){...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a generic type rather than a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) in `dataSet`. `ArrayList dataSet` is equivalent to `ArrayList<Object> dataSet`

In addition code to an interface by using a `List` rather than an `ArrayList`

```
public void onUserTimeChoice(List<Integer> dataSet) {
```

Comment: And while we're at it, you should use `List<Integer>`, it's  better to be more general and code against interfaces (`List` is a interface). Or do you explicitly want the caller to pass a `ArrayList`?